# Gramps: Generate a family graph with the name and picture of each person

Tags: genealogy

I entered my family genealogy tree into [Gramps](https://www.gramps-project.org) (name, picture, children/parents of each person), and now I would like to print on paper a nice graph with pictures showing at least me, my siblings and their partners&kids, and my parents.

I clicked `Reports`>`Graphical reports`>`Ancestor Tree`, it generates a PDF which is perfect except that:

- It is a tree, only showing me and my ancestors (with my siblings). On the other hand, the `Descendants Tree` does not show both of my parents.
- It does not include people's pictures.

  The options' `Display` tab have an editable `Display format` but the [template documentation](https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Display_formatting) does not have a variable for the person's picture.

Ironically, the editing view does show pictures, but I can't use a screenshot of it because it is a tree rather than a graph, I haven't found a way to make it show both my siblings and both of my parents:

[image]

**Question**: How to generate a complete family graph with the name and picture of each person?
Something like this:

[image: Family graph with pictures]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it, it is not perfect but it mostly work:

1. Click `Reports`>`Graphs`>`Family Lines Graph...`
2. In the `Include` tab, make sure `Include thumbnail images of people` is checked
3. The boring part: In `People of Interest`, add all members of your family. For each person, you have to press `+`, select the person from the list of persons, and click `OK`. There seems to be no way to select multiple people at the same time, so it can take a very long time :'-( Fortunately the selection is saved.
4. Press OK.
5. The output gets generated, as PDF or SVG or PNG etc.

Unfortunately the picture resolution is very low (much lower than the original pictures), so better solutions are welcome! :-)